# Available countries list won't appear when set in Localization

Tags: localisation, 4.7, settings

We just upgraded to version 4.7.1, which reset our localization values.

Our forms need to display a list of all possible countries for our contact address fields.

However, when I go to Language and Currency Localization and remove all options from "Available countries," which leaves the field blank, our forms display a squashed box with only one option: the United States.

When I then go back to the Language and Currency Localization page in CiviCRM, I see that the United States has been added back into the Available countries field.

How can I include a list of all countries without manually adding them one by one, which looks to me right now like my only option?

Comment: Can't you not select the possible countries in the `Available countries` field itself and see if it works for you ? as I think `United States` selection is by default given to the available countries field if you leave it as blank.

Comment: Also experience this issue with Joomla 3.4.8 / CiviCRM 4.7.1 / PHP 5.6 (FastCGI) CiviCRM states "To include ALL countries, leave the right-hand box empty". If you do that, Save it, then immediately go back in, "United States" has defaulted. (And my default country is set to "United Kingdom". I have had to go through the list of countries manually, adding each one I anticipate having contacts in!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking how you can select all countries in one go.

You can do this by clicking on the first country, then scroll down, press shift and click on the last country. Now press "Add".

If you want to add or remove countries from the selection press Ctrl and click.

Edit: please note that this only works in CiviCRM 4.6 and before.  It is not possible to do this in CiviCRM 4.7.  See related question - [How can I select all countries to be available for address fields in CiviCRM 4.7?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/how-can-i-select-all-countries-to-be-available-for-address-fields-in-civicrm-4-7)

Comment: I wish that did work. When I click on any of the countries, it adds it to the list and returns to the main screen. There's no opportunity to scroll down, because I'm back to square one.

I have tried shift-clicking and control-clicking with no luck, either.

Comment: I see what you mean, I have tested this out on the demo site and there doesn't appear to be an easy way to select all countries in CiviCRM 4.7.  My answer only works with CiviCRM 4.6 and prior versions.

Comment: This may be a bug in CiviCRM 4.7. I've posted a new question which I hope will clarify this: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/how-can-i-select-all-countries-to-be-available-for-address-fields-in-civicrm-4-7