# Country selection UI in 4.7.x negative feedback

Tags: admin, ui

I am in the process of upgrading sites from CiviCRM 4.6.x to 4.7.x.

One thing we have had to deal with in CiviCRM upgrades, is at each upgrade the list of selected countries always resets itself to United States only. Always I must make sure to stop in at URL:

Home » CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM
Settings - Localization

```
/civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1
```

And insure that all of the countries are in the selected / available list.

On previous versions of CiviCRM, this UI has been a simple HTML multiple pick list control. However with the upgrade to CiviCRM 4.7.x, now it is a fancy AJAX type pick list where I must click, click, click each country one at a time. This is a major PAIN / regression in functionality.

Please revert back to the simple HTML list control.

Oh, and the help text appears to not have been updated to the new UI. It is still as follows: "Available Countries - Which countries are available in the Country selection field when adding or editing contact addresses. Profile and Custom 'Country' fields also use this setting. **To include ALL countries, leave the right-hand box empty.** "

I am thankful,
Michael

Comment: Please see this related post http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/how-can-i-select-all-countries-to-be-available-for-address-fields-in-civicrm-4-7

Answer (score 2):

Terrific! I found a work-around, and here it is! Using Firefox web browser, with the "Web Developer" tool bar extension, select Disable \ Disable JavaScript \ Disable All JavaScipt. Then reload the above specified URL. That will load the page WITHOUT the AJAX / JavaScript multi-select controls... and leave the basic HTML list controls. I was able to quickly select all the countries, and I am cruising along wrapping up this upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

To me the main bug here is needing to readd them after each upgrade. That's a symptom of aomething underlying. Please could you add this to http://issues.civicrm.org and include the previous upgrades you've done where you had to go through this, i.e. 4.5->4.6, 4.6.5 ->4.6.10. This in particular is helpful to tell us when it's from and if it only affects major version updates.

Comment: Yes the country lists at this URL get reset to USA only at each and every point release. The AJAX GUI multi-select is a **MAJOR*** pain to select all countries... I must keep scrolling back up to select the next country. I have been reporting this behavior for some time now. I will look up my old CiviCRM forum posts about it and raise an issue in the URL you kindly provided. The new UI design is definitely a major step back. It was bad enough to have to remember to re-select after each upgrade (which keystroke short cuts were a major breeze to address this), but this new UI it is very slow!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did you add a bug to issues.civicrm.org?

Comment: I just got done with the 4.7.2 --> 4.7.3 upgrade, an this time the country settings held. Perhaps this long troublesome defect has been resolved in the 4.7.x series.

Comment: Neat-glad it got sorted ok.